# I can't see sort options in stackexchange sites when not logged in

Tags: discussion, support

I was going through different stackexchange sites. It is found that sort options are missing when the user is not logged in. I could only see the sort option 'newest' in all of them. Tried this in chrome and firefox. Even in incognito modes, the links are invisible. There was no luck with the hard refresh on all these browsers.

Also I checked in my virtual box IE(where I have not taken any of the stackoverflow site yet) to check whether it is an issue with my cache or cookies, but the issue is replicated. By editing URL, I could sort the questions, but except 'newest' other links are not there (when not logged in).

Does anyone experience this 'lack of sort options'? Can someone please explain the reason for this unusual behavior?
[image: in virtual box IE]

[image: in incognito mode]

[image: in firefox]

**Here is the latest example from meta.stackexchange.com after logged out.**

[image]

Comment: Reason is supplied [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275326/content-does-not-change-when-changing-tabs-on-tagged-for-a-particular-tag-when/275338#275338)

Comment: THank you for your concern..